# Can I recover wallet when lost a bitcoin core wallet dat file

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I recently due to recover PC and lost the Bitcoin core recover dat file, is that possible to just using private key and address to recover it?

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Bitcoin core is an HD wallet and will have many private keys and addresses derived from a master private key. The only provided way to recover the   exact same wallet is to restore a backup.

If you only want to recover control over one address, you can import the corresponding key. Bitcoin core has RPC, CLI and console interfaces that support the import of [private keys](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/importprivkey.html) or [descriptors](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/importdescriptors.html).

It might be prudent to review your backup regime too.